Is there a way to allow scripts from outside sources when making a chrome extension?
I'm making a chrome extension that relies heavily on outside scripts and APIs. I'm trying to use the content-security-policy rule in the manifest file to allow scripts from things like jsdelivr and the such.
This is my manifest file, where the scripts are being allowed. I also need to be able to execute inline code.
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Solvem Probler",
    "description": "It prolbs all your solvems.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_security_policy": [
        "script-src 'self' "URL HERE"; object-src 'self'",
    ],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "index.html",
      "default_icon": "spicon.png"
    },
    "permissions" : [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting"
    
    ]
}

This is my HTML, where I link those scripts:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script src="URL HERE"></script>
    </head>

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?
P.S. I had to trim down the URLS greatly because stack overflow was marking this as spam.
EDIT: When debugging the unpacked extension, it returns the following error:  Invalid value for 'content_security_policy'. Could not load manifest.
